# PHP How to encode text to numeric entity?

Tags: php, xml, dom, encoding, domdocument

I have xml like this:

```
<formula type="inline">
    <default:math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <default:mi>
            &Zopf;
        </default:mi>
    </default:math>
</formula>
```

My goal is to get rid of all special entities like `&Zopf;` by replacing them by their numeric entity presentations.

I tried :

```
$test    = <content of the xml>;
$convmap = array(0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff);
$test    = mb_encode_numericentity($test, $convmap, 'UTF-8');
```

But this will not replace the `&Zopf;` Any idea?

My goal is to get:

```
&#8484;
```

as shown here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2124/index.htm

Thank you.

Comment: So just to be clear, you want to replace the named `&Zopf;` entity with the numerical `&#____;` entity?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That's right.

Comment: May I ask why? They are synonymous, after all...

Comment: Sure. I have to create XMLs and the requirements is to convert all the special html entities to their numeric presentations. For example, when I am oppening the XML with Firefox, I am getting the error on the &Zopf; entity

Comment: Interesting problem... Since named entities require an up-to-date lookup table, I'm not sure PHP will know them all. Where do those entities come from in the first place? The only rock-solid solution would be to not generate them but I guess you're aware of that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, You're right, I am not controling their generation. They are comming from a LaTex to XML conversion library...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your converter is converting your LaTeX into MathML, not HTML entities. You need something that converts directly into HTML character references, or a [MathML to HTML character reference converter](http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/05-character-references).

You should be able to use `htmlentities`:

```
htmlentities($symbolsToEncode, ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8');
```

http://pt1.php.net/htmlentities

You can change `ENT_XML1` to `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` and it will return Unicode Replacement Characters or Hex character references.

As an alternative, you could use `strtr` to convert the characters to something you specify:

```
$chars = array(
    "\x8484" => "&#x8484;"
    ...
);

$convertedXML = strtr($xml, $chars);
```

http://php.net/strtr

[Someone has done something similar on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/inanimatt/879249).

Comment: This will create &amp;Zopf; It is not what I need

Comment: @Milos So you are trying to go in the other direction?

Comment: In fact, if you check here; http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2124/index.htm, instead of &Zopf; I would like to get his HTML Entity (decimal)  &#8484;

Comment: Thanks again, but the `htmlentities($symbolsToEncode, ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');` returns me again &amp;Zipf;, so nothin interesting. I know this function form git, but I can not be sure that the table that I will use is complete

Comment: @Milos Actually you can, as long as it is just for named entities, because there is [a very small number of them](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/sgml/entities.html)

Comment: @Milos Updated my answer. Your converter is not converting your LaTeX into HTML character references, it's converting them into MathML named entities.

Comment: thanks a lot. The ide of using MathML to HTML character reference converter is briliant.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to decode the named entities first:

```
function decodeNamedEntities($string) {
  static $entities = NULL;
  if (NULL === $entities) {
    $entities = array_flip(
      array_diff(
        get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8'),
        get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8')
      )
    );
  }
  return str_replace(array_keys($entities), $entities, $string);
}
```

After that you can use `htmlentities` to encode them in a different format if it is really needed.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot make this work. Could you please provide working example in one of the online php tools?